# Can individual components in assembly mode be edited in Autodesk Inventor?

Tags: 3d-modeling, autodesk-inventor

I'm new to Inventor and still trying to learn how to use it.
I created a part (a simple extrusion of a 2"x2" square) that I plan to use in the assembly many times with differing lengths for framing purposes. I named the extrusion length parameter "len".

In the assembly view, I have 2 instances of my part. If I double click one (change to edit mode) and use the manage parameters button to change the length of one of them, the length of the other instance changes as well. Is there any way to change the parameter for only a single component instance?

Alternatively, is there a better way to manage a group of many parts that only vary in a single parameter than having many part files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the "best" way to do this is with an iPart which allows the creation of families of parts that only vary in a few parameters.

The use of iParts requires Microsoft Excel (the real Microsoft version and not LibreOffice) therefore they are useless for me.

I have since been modeling parts that are similar but may need individual adjustment by copying similar parts after they are initially modeled and having separate files that can diverge. So no, besides iParts, there are not better ways to manage families of similar parts.